# Laravel reusing the framework

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, composer-php, laravel-5.1

I am new to laravel , composer and frameworks.however i have managed to install laravel on my pc via composer. and i have created a project with it using 
`composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name --prefer-dist`

But i got a directory with my projectname on my current working directory with plenty of files in it.
I need to know wheather i could use this same files by copying the files in the folder and using this as my base for all my other projects..or do i need to run the composer command every time? Even if i run it i gets the same files, which i got now right? So could i just backup the files in the folder i got and use it as my base files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well unless you don't have an internet connection there's no point on creating a backup.

Laravel is modular and has external dependencies, so whenever you are creating a new project with composer you are fetching the most recent modules and the most recent Laravel version. But if you use a backup version you might be developing for an outdated version with critical bugs.

Another cool thing is that if you work on different computers, like you have one at work and another at home you don't have to be carrying your backup so you can start a new project by just doing:

`composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name --prefer-dist`

Also I never tested, but I think it takes more time copying a brand new Laravel install with it's dependecies than using composer.

### Composer Offline

Another nice thing about using composer is that it stores everything in it's cache. So imagine this scenario we have an internet connection and create a new Laravel app

```
$ composer create-project laravel/laravel APP1 --prefer-dist
```

Now disconnect your internet, create another folder and install Laravel again

```
$ composer create-project laravel/laravel different-APP2 --prefer-dist
```

When you run the second time and since you don't have internet it will fetch everything from composer cache, but they will be two completely different applications with their own app names and their own application keys

Comment: What if i dont always have an internet connection? @fabio-antunes

Comment: Well composer stores everything in cache, so if you just run the installer, then disconnect your internet and run it again it will install everything from cache

Comment: Does the projectname include in any of the files inside the laravel files?so i will not be able to change the directory name or project name afterwards?

Comment: Am i able to change the project name or folder name afterwards?

Comment: Sure just rename the folder, the app name on the composer command, it's just the name of the folder

Answer (score 0):

You could use this files again, but you won't get the same files running the command *every* time, since the latest version of the laravel project and its dependencies are downloaded.

The project files are [updated regularly](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commits/master). So if you don't have limited bandwidth, you should just create a new project every time.